# Django: problem with merging querysets after annotation

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset, annotate

I have a manager for "Dialog" looking like this:

```
class AnnotationManager(models.Manager):
def get_query_set(self):
    return super(AnnotationManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(
        num_votes=Count('vote', distinct=True),
        num_comments=Count('comment', distinct=True),
        num_commentators = Count('comment__user', distinct=True),
    )
```

Votes and Comments has a ForeignKey to Dialog. Comments has a ForeignKey to User. When I do this:

```
dialogs_queryset = Dialog.public.filter(organization=organization)
dialogs_popularity = dialogs_queryset.exclude(num_comments=0) | dialogs_queryset.exclude(num_votes=0)
```

...dialogs_popularity will never returned the combination, but only the dialogs with more than 0 comments, or if I change the order of the OR, the dialogs with more than 0 votes!

To me, the expected behavior would be to get the dialogs with more than 0 votes AND the dialogs with more than 0 comments.

What am I missing? Or is there a bug in the annotation behavior here?

Answer (score 0):

Did want dialogs with both votes and comments?

```
# must have both a vote and a comment
# aka.  has_comments_and_votes = has_comments AND has_votes
#                              = !(has_no_comments OR has_no_votes)
has_comments = ~Q(num_comments=0)
has_votes = ~Q(num_votes=0)

dialogs_queryset.filter(num_comments__ne=0, num_votes__ne=0)
# or with Q objects
dialogs_queryset.filter(has_comments & has_votes)
dialogs_queryset.exclude(~has_comments | ~has_votes)
```

Or dialogs having either votes, comments or both. (What you want based on comment.)

```
# must have at least 1 vote or 1 comment
# aka. has_comments_or_votes = has_comments OR has_votes
#                            = !(has_no_comments AND has_no_votes)
dialogs_queryset.exclude(num_comments=0, num_votes=0)
# again with Q objects
dialogs_queryset.filter(has_comments | has_votes)  # easiest to read!
dialogs_queryset.exclude(~has_comments & ~has_votes)
```

I added the [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) examples because the "|" in your code sample seemed to be hinting at them and they make it easier to create ORed queries.

EDIT:
I added `has_comments` and `has_votes` to make things a little easier to read.

Comment: it appears you've reversed your code blocks and their descriptions.

Comment: I added more to the description of each code block.  Please take another look and give more explicit details on how the description is reversed.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. To clearify I  was looking for dialogs having either votes, comments or both. I tried your code and it still does not work.


dialogs_queryset.filter(num_comments__ne=0, num_votes__ne=0)
...gives me dialogs with no votes AND no comments.


dialogs_queryset.exclude(num_comments=0, num_votes=0)
...gives me dialogs with comments AND votes.


The code just does not behave the way I expect when I do this on annotated values!

Comment: This: dialogs_popularity = dialogs_queryset.filter(Q(num_comments=0) & Q(num_votes=0))

... gives the same result as the exact same thing but replacing filter with exclude. Is that really weird?

Comment: I now managed to write two lines of code that does the trick, but it feels like a strange aproach!
q1 = dialogs_queryset.exclude(Q(num_comments=0) | Q(num_votes=0))
dialogs_popularity = dialogs_queryset | q1

Comment: Replacing 'filter' with 'exclude' is giving you the same results?  That is bad and suggests that something is very wrong.  Make sure that your annotations are giving you the expected results before tackling the filtering logic.  I updated the answer based on your comments.